# Solr + Solarium: counter does not work with multi select facets

Tags: php, solr, solr4, faceted-search, solarium

I'm working with Solr + Solarium. I have defined a multi facet search. Each facet options has counters behind them showing the number of returned results when you click on it.

When selecting an option within a multi-select facet I would expect that the counters of the others facets still work.

There are results in solr. In my old code (single select facets) it returned values for petrol/diesel.

E.g. the following 2 facets:

Car brands:
-volvo (3)
-mazda (2)
-volkswagen (5)

Fuel:
-Diesel (4)
-Petrol (6)

Now i would like to be able to select Volvo AND Mazda. After selecting Volvo solr/solarium is returning the following 2 facets:

Brand:
-volvo (3) - selected
-mazda (2)
-volkswagen (5)

Fuel:
-Diesel (0)
-Petrol (0)

The brand facet is good. I would expect the Fuel facet counter to return the number of Diesel/Petrol cars from volvo. E.g:
-Diesel (2)
-Petrol (1)

My code:

```
    $exclude= array("brand");
    $q_brand = id_brand:volvo
    $q_fuel = "";

    // create a client instance
    $client = new Solarium_Client($config);

    // get a select query instance
    $query = $client->createSelect();
    $query->createFilterQuery(array('key'=>'id_brand', 'query'=>'$q_brand', 'tag'=>'brand'));
    $query->createFilterQuery(array('key'=>'id_fuel',  'query'=>'$q_fuel', 'tag'=>'fuel'));

    // get the facetset component
    $facetSet = $query->getFacetSet();
    $facetSet->createFacetField('id_brand')->setField('id_brand')->setExcludes($exclude);
    $facetSet->createFacetField('id_fuel')->setField('id_fuel');

    // this executes the query and returns the result
    $resultset = $client->select($query);

    // display facet counts
    echo '<hr/>Facet counts for field "id_brand":<br/>';
    $facet = $resultset->getFacetSet()->getFacet('id_brand');
    foreach ($facet as $value => $count) {
        echo $value . ' [' . $count . ']<br/>';
    }

    // display facet counts
    echo '<hr/>Facet counts for field "id_fuel":<br/>';
    $facet = $resultset->getFacetSet()->getFacet('id_fuel');
    foreach ($facet as $value => $count) {
        echo $value . ' [' . $count . ']<br/>';
    }
```

Comment: This can't be the actual code you're using, there are syntax errors and weird stuff all over the place. If you have a sample .json-file and the schema you're using for testing, that would be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed a syntax mistake. I removed the quotation for `'query'` in the array of `createfilterquery`. I also added quotes to the var `$q_brand`. Which was a typo.

**Old:**

```
$query->createFilterQuery(array('key'=>'id_brand', 'query'=>'$q_brand', 'tag'=>'brand'));
$query->createFilterQuery(array('key'=>'id_fuel',  'query'=>'$q_fuel', 'tag'=>'fuel'));
```

**New:**

```
$query->createFilterQuery(array('key'=>'id_brand', 'query'=>$q_brand, 'tag'=>'brand'));
$query->createFilterQuery(array('key'=>'id_fuel',  'query'=>$q_fuel, 'tag'=>'fuel'));
```